# Group Policy | New Password Policy for a few users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

We have a few users that are traveling and I would like their passwords to be changed more often than the rest of the folks in the office. How should I go about creating a new policy with their password restrictions, age, etc. and ensure it only gets applied to those few individuals?

Comment: use Fine-Grained Password Policies. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Im trying to add a new fine grained password policy but getting an error:

The term 'New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable programs. Check spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, reputation is too low to reply to comment, so posting this as an answer.

The Powershell commandlet New-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy requires the active directory module to be loaded. First try "Import-Module ActiveDirectory"

If that doesn't work, see if it is available. "Get-Module –ListAvailable" will show you what is available. If it is not available, install Remote Server Administration Tools.

Comment: Active Directory is available - http://prntscr.com/6xatd2

Comment: and still won't recognize New-FineGrainedPasswordPolicy

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new PSO with the ADSI editor and a new user group for the user you wish to get this password setting object.

To create an PSO:

Click Start - run type adsiedit.msc and connect to your domain with FQDN
browse to DC=domain_name CN=SYSTEm CN=Password Settings Container and right click it and say new.
Fill in your group name to msDS-PSOAppliesTo

More about creating PSO read here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754461(v=ws.10).aspx